# C++, Learning, Basic Return Primes

Tags: c++, boolean, primes

My goal is that: the program return the list of numbers in the vector i made, which are the primes numbers, the code is wrong,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

vector < int > L;
bool mark[10];
void colador()
{
    fill(mark,mark+10, false);
    for(int i=2; i*i <=10; i++)
    {
        if(!mark[i])
        {
            L.push_back(i); 
            for(int j=i*i; j<=10; j+=i)
            {
                mark[j]=true;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int e=sqrt(10)+1; e<=10; e++)
    {
        if(!mark[e])
        {
            L.push_back(e);
        }
    }
}



int main()
{
    for( int i=0; i<=9; i++)
    {
        cout << L[i] << endl ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When i compile it, the program doesn't show me anything. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, general functions are not automatically executed just by defining. You have to call them to execute them.

Secondly, the loop in the `main()` is wrong. It may read out-of-range without checking.

Also your `colador()` function is wrong. The array `mark` has only 10 elements (`mark[0]` to `mark[9]`), but you are accessing out-of-range `mark[10]`.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm> // for std::fill()
using namespace std;

vector < int > L;
bool mark[10];
void colador(){
    fill(mark,mark+10, false);
    for(int i=2; i*i <=10; i++)
    {
        if(!mark[i]){
            L.push_back(i);
            for(int j=i*i; j<10; j+=i){mark[j]=true;} // use j<10, not j<=10
        }


    }
    for(int e=sqrt(10)+1; e<10; e++){ // use e<10, not e<=10
        if(!mark[e]){L.push_back(e);}

    }
}

int main(){
    colador(); // call the function

#if 1
    // for modern compiler (C++11 or later)
    for( int e : L ){cout << e << endl ;}
#else
    // for old compiler
    for( size_t i=0; i<L.size(); i++){cout << L[i] << endl ;}
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not make `colador` return the vector or pass it by reference

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues in your code,

the most relevant one is that your function `void colador()` is not going to be called by itself...

you need to call that BEFORE doing the `for( int i=0; i<=9; i++)`